# Android application update in background

Tags: android, google-play-services

Is there any way to update the android application which is already in Play Store through API calls or by any other way in background other than updating it in PlayStore.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "update'? You can't build new activities and features in your app any other way that upgrading by the play store

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android application self-update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9045837/android-application-self-update)

Comment: Means if the application is updated in playstore.. It should be downloaded and installed directly without prompting the user about the update.

Comment: you can't do it. Non-system apps can't install APKs without a prompt.

Comment: It depends. If you don't need extra permissions and user has enabled auto update and connected to wifi, your app gets updated in the background. For updating via your own api, you need system permissions.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the information. :)